# How do I link a tab view to a window controller in Xcode 6 (Swift)?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, storyboard

I am new to Xcode and Swift. I prefer to learn through experience, so I am doing exactly that with Xcode. I do have moderate experience with C# on Visual Studio, however. I am trying to manage the window for a tab view I have created. I unfortunately do not know how to link this window to the tab view. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. :)

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found out how! I just had to control click and drag from the Window Controller's class (an     NSWindow    class) to the view controller and then make the window controller the entry point of the program.